# What's the name of camera tiles view in agora.io?

Tags: agora.io

I'm just playing around with agora.io, WebRTC and I want to implement a "camera tile view". I hope you understand what I mean, so all the (small) cameras of the users should be displayed in a row/table one next to each other or in a list, if too many users. The active speaking user gets a border around his camera view or sth like that.
Can anybody tell me the name of this kind of view or point me to a location, where I can check some samples about this?
Best regards, Alex

Comment: https://github.com/EkaanshArora/Agora-React-Web-UIKit/

Answer (score 1):

The Agora SDK's provide all the API's for building your own Ui, so there is no method within the SDK for generating a tile view, you would have to do that yourself.

That being said, the Agora developer community has some open source UI Kits that serve as a good starter template for your UI that you can adjust. The Agora Web UIKit supports tile view as the default.

- Vanilla JS: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/adding-video-chat-or-live-streaming-to-your-website-in-5-lines-of-code-using-the-agora-web-uikit/
- React: https://agoraio-community.github.io/Web-React-UIKit/